# Installing PHP Zip Extension in CentOS

Tags: php, centos, zip, pear, php-extension

I'm attempting to install the PHP Zip extension in CentOS.

My server does not have external internet access, so I downloaded it myself from PECL: http://pecl.php.net/package/zip.  I chose 1.10.2, the latest "stable" release, and transferred it to my server.

I ran:

```
pear install zip-1.10.2.tgz
```

and added

```
extension=zip.so
```

to php.ini as instructed.  I can see that zip.so was created and placed in the right extension_dir folder as well.  I restarted apache and then checked to see if it was loaded by running:

```
php -m
```

Despite all of this, "zip" is still not in that list.

Am I missing a step or doing something wrong?  I thought this should be really simple, and I'm starting to feel pretty dumb, haha.

Other probably important stuff:

CentOS
Apache 2.2.3
PHP 5.2.16

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may have several `php.ini` files, one for CLI and one for apache. Run `php --ini` to see where the CLI ini location is.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That returns the following (sorry for this I'm not sure how to linebreak in a comment): Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none).  Also, find / -name "php.ini" tells me that this is the only php.ini file on the box

Comment: It did not load any configuration file. That's your problem. My PHP also shows a "configuration file (php.ini) path" with `php --ini`. Use `$ strace -eopen php --ini` to find out where you php looks for the .ini file.

Comment: Sorry for pretty much letting this die without explanation.  `php --ini` says the config file path is `/usr/bin` ...do I just need to move it there?  Also, if nothing from the config file is taking effect does PHP come with a set of defaults it uses instead?

Comment: yes, there are default values. they are documented in the php manual. try to move the php.ini to the path you found.

Answer (score 102):

This is how I installed it on my machine (ubuntu):

php 7:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

php 5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-zip
```

Make sure to restart your server afterwards.

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `sudo service nginx restart`

*PS: If you are using centOS, please check above **cweiske**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18822464/2873538) 

But if you are using a Debian derivated OS, this solution should help you installing php zip extension.*

Comment: You seem to suggest to use a package manager to solve or prevent any issues. CentOS seems to use [yum](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-managing-packages.html#sn-yum-installing-withrepositories) as a package manager.

Comment: for php7.1
sudo apt install php7.1-zip

Comment: has anyone been able to install the zip extension for `php7.2` ? it keep on saying **E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zip'** i have tried alot of variations but none work, i have **PHP Version 7.2.17-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+3**

Comment: Note that the question was about CentOS and not Ubuntu (I tried to clarify that in the title)

Answer (score 26):

Simply use `sudo yum install php-zip`

Comment: The question specifies that this is for CentOS, not Ubuntu. CentOS uses yum not apt-get

Comment: Or `sudo apt-get install php-zip`

Answer (score 23):

for PHP 7.3 / Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install php7.3-zip
```

for PHP 7.4

```
sudo apt install php7.4-zip
```

Comment: "Unable to locate package php7.3-zip"

Comment: Note that the question was about CentOS and not Ubuntu

Answer (score 17):

**1 Step -** Install a required extension

```
sudo apt-get install libz-dev libzip-dev -y
```

**2 Step -** Install the PHP extension

```
pecl install zlib zip
```

**3 Step -** Restart your Apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

[image: Enable PHP ZIP Extension]

> If does not work you can check if the zip.ini is called in your phpinfo, to check if the zip.so was included.

Comment: ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/zip/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config' failed

Comment: Note that the question was about CentOS and not Ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

For php 7.3 on **ubuntu** 16.04

`sudo apt-get install php7.3-zip`

Comment: Note that the question was about CentOS and not Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

The best way to install the Zip extension in php7.2 on CentOS would be as below:

1. Find the available extention by searching with yum command

   yum search zip
2. This will list all the zip packages. We need to look for the php7.2 zip package
   [image]

3. Then if your php version is 7.2 then run the command

   yum install ea-php72-php-zip

This will definetly resolve your issue.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 3):

On Amazon Linux 2 and PHP 7.4 I finally got PHP-ZIP to install and I hope it helps someone else - by the following (note the yum install command has extra common modules also included you may not need them all):

```
sudo yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

sudo yum -y install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

sudo yum -y install yum-utils

sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74

sudo yum update

sudo yum install php php-cli php-fpm php-mysqlnd php-zip php-devel php-gd php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath php-json

sudo pecl install zip

php --modules

sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: no need to "pecl install", ZIP extension available in the "remi-php74" repository !

Comment: It didn't show up in my list of installed modules until i did. But I may have had something else wrong from my numerous attempts. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to install it on CentOS 7 for php 7.1. In my case yum package `php-zip` was unavailable in remi repo, but I could install it using different name

```
yum install php-pecl-zip
```

So if you can't find it by query `php-zip`, try searching for `php-pecl-zip`.

Comment: "yum install php-zip"  also works, as for any ext, don't rely on package name.

Answer (score 1):

If you use php5.6 then execute this:

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip`

Comment: >CentOS Apache 2.2.3 PHP 5.2.16

Comment: I get `E: Unable to locate package php5.6-zip`.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP5 version do not support in Ubuntu 18.04+ versions, so you have to do that configure manually from the source files. If you are using [php-5.3.29](https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2),

```
# cd /usr/local/src/php-5.3.29
# ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysql=MySQL_LOCATION/mysql --prefix=/usr/local/apache/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache/php --disable-cgi --with-zlib --with-gettext --with-gdbm --with-curl --enable-zip --with-xml --with-json --enable-shmop
# make
# make install
```

Restart the Apache server and check phpinfo function on the browser `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`

Note: Please change the MySQL_Location: --with-mysql=MySQL_LOCATION/mysql

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing the repository list with:

[http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu%20bionic-security) main universe http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe

But none of them seem to work, but I finally found a repository that works running the following command

add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

And then updating and installing normally the package using apt-get

As you can see it's installed at last.

Answer (score 1):

For those who need to install the `zip` extension in a Docker image being built.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libzip-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Comment: This took forever to find. Thanks for putting this here!