# Install php-zip on php 5.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, zip

I can't install php-zip on my Ubuntu VM with the last php5.6.

Can't find find anything clear on it.

I still get that Apache error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /var/www/uta/system/library/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/...
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php ? I know recompiling PHP from source is not ideal but it's the most reliable way to get exactly what you need out of it, in my opinion.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Try either

- `sudo apt-get install php-zip` or
- `sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip`

Then, you might have to restart your web server.

- `sudo service apache2 restart` or
- `sudo service nginx restart`

If you are installing on centos or fedora OS then use yum in place of apt-get. example:-

`sudo yum install php-zip` or
`sudo yum install php5.6-zip` and 
`sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: apt-get install php5.6-zip works there thanks

Comment: works for `php-7.0` also

Comment: we must restart apache server to check effect!

Comment: Depending on PHP version, you'll have to install php5.6-zip, php7.0-zip, php7.1-zip php7.2-zip. You may have 3 PHP version (that's my case). Be sure to get the one you need. It's not always easy to know if you use a CMS for example.

Comment: Nailed it, thanks.  I had recently updated my PHP version, so needed to re-install the correct version of php5.6.zip. Thanks

Comment: I am now getting `Unable to locate package` for both those `apt-get`s. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774568/installing-php-zip-extension may help more now.

Comment: For php 7 sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip

Comment: Works for php 7.2 with `sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip`

Comment: Works for php 7.3 with `apt install php7.3-zip`