# Unable to install zip extention for php

Tags: php, zip, opencart-3

I am trying to install a zip extension to my localhost in order to install open cart but everything seems like failing and I am getting this message.

> Warning: ZIP extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!

I have tried  adding

```
extension=zip.so
```

To my ini I have installed.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Still, there is no zip

```
php -m
```

What I have to do?

Comment: what's `php -v` output?

Comment: PHP 7.2.3-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 12:03:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.3-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Try install php7.2 zip.

Comment: sudo: unable to resolve host xxxxxx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zip' @KrisRoofe

Comment: what's `uname -a` output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18774568/6521116

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38104397/6521116

Comment: Both i have tried

Comment: uname -a
Linux holla 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux