# How to Enable PHP Zip module on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed Wordpress on Google Cloud. I am getting this error. Oops, Unyson Backup requires PHP Zip module but it is not enabled on your server. If you are not familiar with PHP Zip module, please contact your hosting provider.

My Question is how to enable php zip module on my google compute engine?

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install php-zip on php 5.6 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104348/install-php-zip-on-php-5-6-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

First you need SSH access to a VM running your Wordpress.

Usually it's enough to type `sudo apt install php-zip` (for Ubuntu & Debian) or `sudo yum install php-zip` (for Fedora & CentOS). It will install the PHP extension and now just restart the service `sudo service httpd restart`.

This [question was also discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774568/installing-php-zip-extension) and has several answers.

Comment: I've installed it as you indicate but when I do `php -m` I don't see it listed.  I've added a `/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini` but it doesn't help.  what else do I need?

Answer (score 0):

if using share hosting godaddy need install mudule

1.-Login in cpanal and search php

https://i.stack.imgur.com/596io.png

Select package PHP PEAR

in search input type zip and click button go

[type zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLDlA.png)

after click install
[install module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Ph0.png)

2.-Return dashboard and search php and select php version
[search php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VDGN.png)

Search modulo zip and click checkbox for active
[Active module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z42iY.png)

3.-Return dashboard wordpress and continue intall demo

Already