# php5.6-zip not available?

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-5.6, php-ziparchive

I am currently using php 5.6 for one of my very old project, it is on ubuntu 16.04. I needed to install php-zip extension on it. I tried `apt-get install php5.6-zip`, did not work. Showed there is no package with that name. So, I searched and it seemed right, I did `sudo apt-cache search php5.6-*` and there were other php5.6 extensions, but not php-zip. Is there any way I can still install php5.6-zip?

Comment: What about `php5-zip` ?  That was [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37018618/7644018)

Comment: tried, did not work.